# How to get column total for a table with two pivots

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table joining two table having two pivots, Now I intend to get the total of all the column values for each row.

Below is my code which I am currently working on:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT        
         time_tracker.date, 
         Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS username, 
         (CASE 
             WHEN ((datepart(hour, chk_in)) >= 12 OR
                   (datepart(hour, chk_out)) < 16) 
                THEN 0.5 
                ELSE 1 
          END) AS late, 
         TypeOfLeaves.leave_type, Userleavetyp.no_of_days
     FROM            
         Users 
     INNER JOIN
         time_tracker ON Users.ID = time_tracker.fk_userid 
     INNER JOIN
         Userleavetyp ON Users.ID = Userleavetyp.fk_user 
     INNER JOIN
         TypeOfLeaves ON Userleavetyp.fk_tol = TypeOfLeaves.ID
     WHERE        
         (Users.FK_Status = 1)) AS P
```

> For month days

```
PIVOT
    (SUM(late) FOR date IN ("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-14", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21", "2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-26", "2018-01-27", "2018-01-28", "2018-01-29", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31")
      ) AS pv1
```

> For leave type

```
PIVOT
    (SUM(no_of_days)  
     FOR leave_type IN ([Casual Leave], [Paid Leave], [Complimentary Leave])) AS pv2
```

I want the desired result to be something like this

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vppu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can do:

- Sum all pivoted columns: add an additional expression that sums all results. Change:

  ```
  SELECT
      *
  FROM
      --...
  ```

  To:

  ```
  SELECT
      *,
      Total = ISNULL([2018-01-01], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-02], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-03], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-04], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-05], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-06], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-07], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-08], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-09], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-10], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-11], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-12], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-13], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-14], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-15], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-16], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-17], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-18], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-19], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-20], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-21], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-22], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-23], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-24], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-25], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-26], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-27], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-28], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-29], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-30], 0) 
          + ISNULL([2018-01-31], 0)
  FROM
      --...
  ```
- Calculate the total on another subquery and join at the end to retrieve the total:

  ```
  ;WITH ToPivot AS
  (
      SELECT        
           time_tracker.date, 
           Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS username, 
           (CASE 
               WHEN ((datepart(hour, chk_in)) >= 12 OR
                     (datepart(hour, chk_out)) < 16) 
                  THEN 0.5 
                  ELSE 1 
            END) AS late, 
           TypeOfLeaves.leave_type, 
           Userleavetyp.no_of_days
       FROM            
           Users 
       INNER JOIN
           time_tracker ON Users.ID = time_tracker.fk_userid 
       INNER JOIN
           Userleavetyp ON Users.ID = Userleavetyp.fk_user 
       INNER JOIN
           TypeOfLeaves ON Userleavetyp.fk_tol = TypeOfLeaves.ID
       WHERE        
           (Users.FK_Status = 1)
  ),
  LateTotals AS 
  (
      SELECT
          T.username,
          Total = SUM(late)
      FROM
          ToPivot AS T
      WHERE
          T.date IN ('2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-08', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-13', '2018-01-14', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-17', '2018-01-18', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-20', '2018-01-21', '2018-01-22', '2018-01-23', '2018-01-24', '2018-01-25', '2018-01-26', '2018-01-27', '2018-01-28', '2018-01-29', '2018-01-30', '2018-01-31')
      GROUP BY
          T.username
  )
  SELECT
      PV2.*,
      L.Total
  FROM
      ToPivot AS P
      PIVOT
          (SUM(late) FOR date IN ("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06", "2018-01-07", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-10", "2018-01-11", "2018-01-12", "2018-01-13", "2018-01-14", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", "2018-01-18", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-21", "2018-01-22", "2018-01-23", "2018-01-24", "2018-01-25", "2018-01-26", "2018-01-27", "2018-01-28", "2018-01-29", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31")
        ) AS pv1
      PIVOT
          (SUM(no_of_days)  
          FOR leave_type IN ([Casual Leave], [Paid Leave], [Complimentary Leave])
          ) AS pv2
      LEFT JOIN LateTotals AS L ON L.username = pv2.username
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, I tried your query but I am getting this error: The multi-part identifier "P.username" could not be bound.

Comment: @devbarrierbreak it was a typo on the last join, it's corrected now.

Comment: Thanks @Ezlo I tried your updated query it works but now the problem is it gives multiple rows for each user and the total also seems to be invalid.

Comment: @devbarrierbreak I've edited the subquery to do a day per day filter instead of a between. I guessed you need your total by username since it's the only column that gets displayed on your expected outcome. If there are other columns you will have to add them to the GROUP BY (and select list) in the LateTotals subquery and also add them on the join at the end.

Comment: I have edited my question and shared the image of the output I require @Elzo

Comment: I did as you suggested it works,I am getting the counts as required, but now I need to apply the second pivot for leaves that I had used in my previous query. Can you give me a hit as how it can be done.@Elzo

Comment: @devbarrierbreak just add the 2nd pivot, it's set on my answer.

Comment: I used a distinct on the last query and it work like a charm.Thanks @Ezlo for the help.